# rust cannot implement From for type of generic type

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to implement the From trait that takes as input any iterator with Item = String, but if i pass in an iterator of type Args the compiler tells me:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Data: std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<std::env::Args>>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:19:20
   |
19 |     let arg_data = Data::from(Box::new(std::env::args()));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<std::env::Args>>` is not implemented for `Data`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Data as std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = std::string::String> + 'static)>>>
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

my code is:

```
struct Data {
    strings: Vec<String>,
}

impl From<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>> for Data {
    fn from(string_iterator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>) -> Self {
        let mut vector = Vec::new();

        for s in string_iterator {
            vector.push(s)
        }

        Data { strings: vector }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arg_data = Data::from(Box::new(std::env::args()));

    for a in arg_data.strings {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve it but I'm not enough of a generics expert to know why it needs to be this way.

Change to

```
let arg_data = Data::from(Box::new(std::env::args()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>);
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=341162e238fde6ef56a49ebd5a48fa16